# Building rqt (plus all plugins) from source - qt_gui_main() can't find any plugins

Tags: ros, debian, rqt, jessie, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have just finished building `rqt` from source for **ROS Indigo** on my Debian Jessie without any errors. However when I try to run `rqt_graph` for example I get:

```
qt_gui_main() found no plugin matching "rqt_graph.ros_graph.RosGraph"
```

Next thing I did was to open `rqt`. It opens fine however I can't see a single plugin inside the plugin menu even though I have `rqt_graph`, `rqt_console` etc. (full `rqt_common_plugins` metapackage was installed). The executables are there (that is why the terminal didn't throw an error at me that the command was not found when calling `rqt_graph`) but there seems to be missing something and I don't know what.

Any ideas what's going on here? All the source war pulled via `wstool` and `rosdep` (as described in the tutorial about installing ROS on Debian).

**EDIT:** Running `rqt --list-plugins` doesn't return anything at all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217992/building-rqt-(plus-all-plugins)-from-source---qt_gui_main()-can%27t-find-any-plugins/) by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2015-09-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Already answered [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/166851/rqt-reconfigure-no-plugin-found/?answer=173768#post-id-173768). It seems that `source`-ing my `~/.bashrc` is not enough and I have to delete `~/.config/ros.org/rqt_gui.ini` too. Now every thing is working the way it should be. ^_^

---

Originally posted by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) with karma: 299 on 2015-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5